# sequelize query where like

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

The query should return both sample data below since it matches the context data filename and employeeId but my current query only returns the DOC.doc . How do we correct this in sequelize ? using like ?

```
#Sample context.data.filename
DOC.doc

#Sample Record

DOC.doc
DOC-1.doc
```

#Code

```
const file = await context.service.Model.findAll({
    where: {
      employeeId: record.id,
      filename: {
        [Op.like]: `%${context.data.filename}%`,
      },
    },
    paranoid: false,
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering just the data that you provided, I think the code bellow is gonna work.

```js
const file = await context.service.Model.findAll({
  where: {
    employeeId: record.id,
    filename: {
      [Op.like]: 'DOC%'
    }
  },
  paranoid: false
});
```

But, for more operations with `like`, you should see the following table (from [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) site):

[image: Table from site above]